# How to select the recently registered data in between two given date

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

How to get the recent registered data from database using dataset in C#.

I want to get the recent registered data between two given date. 
The data must not exist before start Month.

**Please help me as I am stuck here.**

```
public DataSet getRecentRegistrations(DateTime startMonth, DateTime endMonth, long setaCode)
{
    var query = (from _transaction in _entities.LevyTransactions
                 join _seta in _entities.Setas on _transaction.SetaCode equals _seta.SetaCode
                 join company_details in _entities.Organisations on _transaction.Refno equals company_details.Refno
                 where(_transaction.TransactionDate >= startMonth || startMonth == null) && (_transaction.TransactionDate <= endMonth || endMonth == null) && (_transaction.SetaCode == setaCode || setaCode < 0)
                 select new
                 {
                     SetaCode= _transaction.SetaCode,
                     RefNo = company_details.Refno,
                     TradingName = company_details.TradingName,
                     Seta=_transaction.SetaCode+" - "+_seta.Description,
                     SetaLevy = _transaction.SetaLevy,
                     SetaInterest = _transaction.SetaInterest,
                     SetaAdmin = _transaction.SetaAdmin,
                     SetaPenalty = _transaction.SetaPenalty,
                     TotalSetaCollected = _transaction.TotalSetaCollected
                 });

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
    ds.Tables.Add(headerTable("Transaction Month From : " + HelperService.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", startMonth) + " To : " + HelperService.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", endMonth), "Recently Registered Companies")); ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Table2";
    var setaRows = (from DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                    select new {
                                SetaCode = dRow["SetaCode"], Seta = dRow["Seta"] 
                                }).Distinct();
    ds.Tables.Add(setaRows.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[2].TableName = "Table3";
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What is the expected result?

Comment: Check Database to make sure dates are DateTime type and not strings (varchar).  If you have string you need to use DataTime.Parse().

Comment: The table is like this